# Force Touch TableView Cell Rounded Peek and Pop - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, 3dtouch, force-touch

While peek and popping in a tableView, how do I make my `previewingContext.sourceRect` rounded?

At the moment:

1. Force Touch on TableView Cell
2. Set the previewing delegate as such:

   previewingContext.sourecRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)

I have already tried setting the cell's `cell.layer.cornerRadius` & `cell.layer.maskToBounds = true` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, However the previewing soruce rect is still a perfect rectangle.

Relevant code:

UIVIewControllerPreviewingDelegate

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    if tableView.isEditing == false {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else {
            print("Nil Cell Found: \(location)")
            return nil }
        guard let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view") as? ViewController else { return nil }


        previewingContext.sourceRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)


        return detailVC

    } else {
        return nil

    }
}
```

TableView CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { fatalError("No cell with identifier: cell") }

            cell.titleLabel.text = "temp"

//            cell.inputView?.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
//            cell.inputView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

//            cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
//            cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = true

            return cell

        }

    }
```

Currently when just force touching on a tableview cell the blue box in the image below is selected and is the sourcerect, however I want the orange rounded rect (of one cell) to be the source rect.

[image]

Comment: Did you also set `layer.masksToBounds = true`?

Comment: Yes, edited question to reflect that

Comment: without your current code i think nobody can help so much. please post relevant code snippets

Comment: Updated with relevant code

Comment: Since you're passing in a `CGRect`, I doubt you'll be able to let the previewing delegate know about the corner radius you want.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, i just dont know if its possible / how to perform this differently without using a CGRect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your `Peek` to be circle then `Pop` as a normal `ViewController`? 
Because sourceRect is the source of your Preview (in this case your cell) and not your actual Preview.

Try this if you want your Peek to become a circle, and Pop normally:

On your `previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?` add this before you return

```
detailVC.view.layer.cornerRadius = detailVC.view.bounds.width / 2
detailVC.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

And on your `previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController)` add this before you show

```
detailVC.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0
show(detailVC, sender: self)
```

Comment: Im looking for the previewing context source rect to be a rounded rect cell.  I would like both the peek and pop to remain vanilla.  However when i start to force touch on my tableview cell, the entire cell (as a rectangle) is used. I will update my post with an image displaying what i am trying to achieve